# Applying less generated css to all the html table except th elements

Tags: javascript, css, less

I have the following html code

```
<textarea name="mytextarea" id="mytextarea" rows="10" cols="50">
color:red;
.yellow {
 color : yellow;
}
</textarea><br/>
<button id="mybutton">Parse</button><br/>
Content parsed : <br/>
<p id="parsedContent"></p>
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>A</th>
            <th>B</th>
            <th>C</th>
            <th>D</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>1</th>
            <td>Ya</td>
            <td class="yellow">Hey</td>
            <td>Ho</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>2</th>
            <td>11</td>
            <td>100</td>
            <td>27</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>3</th>
            <td>sadd</td>
            <td>zaa</td>
            <td>ddd</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

This is used to generate some css via a user input and insert dynamically the css generated to the head of the document.
I use the folowing javascript code to generate the css with the lesscss parser:

```
$('#mybutton').on('click',function(){
    content = 'table tbody {'+$('#mytextarea').val()+'}';

    var parser = new(less.Parser);
    parser.parse(content, function (err, tree) {
        if (!err) {
            if($('#headCss').length===0){
                $('head').append('<style id="headCss"></style>');
            }
            css = tree.toCSS();
            console.log(tree);
            $('#headCss').text(css);
            $('#parsedContent').text(css);
        }else{
            $('#parsedContent').text(err);
        }
    });
});
$('#mybutton').click();
```

I need to apply the css generated to the table but it should not be applied to the table head (column and rows).
Is there a way to do this with only pure css on the textarea (not less).

Here a jsfiddle with the code : http://jsfiddle.net/Jiwoks/Lkz0mhor/
In this exemple I don't want row headers to be red, only td elements.

Any help much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put this code in the js.
I just noticed that you used `<th>`s as the header, so the `:not(:first-child)` is not needed.

```
content = 'table tbody td {'+$('#mytextarea').val()+'}';
```

In the JS.

Now this code selects the `td`s, which prevents the `.yellow` class from having any effect, since it looks for an element inside the `td` with the `.yellow` class, rather than the `td` itself.

You can get around this by modifying the input:

```
color:red;
&.yellow {
 color : yellow;
}
```

However, since you want only pure css in the `textarea` input, you can modify it inside the code instead. For example with this line:

```
content = content.replace(/^\./mg, '&.');
```

It replaces all dots at the start of a line with `&.`

http://jsfiddle.net/Lkz0mhor/3/

Comment: Thanks but the yellow class is not anymore applied to the td element.
I have tried more or less like you `table tbody :not(th)` but it's the same problem

Comment: @Jiwoks, oh, yes, the issue is that I select the tds which has no descendant with class `.yellow`. I'll try something else.

Comment: It's a good idea! Just need to add the modifier g to make a global search.
Thanks ;)